# I want to migrate orders and other data into Magento. How do I access the database?

Tags: migration

I want to migrate order and customer data into Magento. How do I access the MySQL database?

Comment: Set database credential in data migration tool config file.

Answer (score 0):

For Database Access

```
Please download https://www.adminer.org/ adminer file and upload on your root server adminer.php file.
Then run your website url with 
http://localhost/magentostoreurl/adminer.php
or
http://magentostoreurl/adminer.php
```

For Database Connection

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
// Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('any_table_name'); 
//gives table name with prefix
```

Select Query

```
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Insert Query

```
$sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (field1, field2) Values ('val1','val2')";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Update Query

```
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set field = 'value' where field = value";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Delete Query

```
$sql = "Delete FROM " . $tableName." Where field = value ";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Hope It Works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you:

1. Follow the migration document of Magento here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html
2. You need to find an reliable automated data migration service to help you transfer data such as products, categories and orders from your old store on Magento 1 to Magento 2 smoothly, quickly and safely.